# Como fazer um redirecionamento para finalizar compra sem passar pelo carrinho do Woocomerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Alguém aqui sabe como fazer um redirecionamento para a página de finalização de compra do WooCommerce quando clicar para comprar um produto?
(Por padrão o WooCommerce adiciona ao carrinho o produto e a pessoa é obrigada ir no carrinho para finalizar a compra)

Comment: muito obrigado deu certo
porem deixei carinho , com cart mesmo

Answer (score 6):

## Última versão

Podes ver na [documentação](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/configuring-woocommerce-settings/) que tens opção para configurar a página do carrinho de forma a que quando é suposto acedermos ao carrinho, vamos estar a aceder a uma outra página.

Assim sendo, duas coisas para deixar o visitante a ir para o "Checkout" quando clica em "comprar":

1. Acedes a Woocommerce > Settings

   Marcar a opção para direccionar o visitante para o carrinho quando usado o botão "comprar":

   [image: Captura de Tela]
2. Acedes a Woocommerce > Settings > Checkout (Tab):

   Onde se lê "Cart", escolhes "Checkout" para a opção "Cart page" de forma a que a página do carrinho seja efectivamente o "Checkout":

   [image: Captura de tela]

## Versão 2.1 ou superior

Outro método para versões a partir da 2.1 é criar um filtro no ficheiro `functions.php`:

```php
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');

function redirect_to_checkout() {
    return WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
}
```

## Versão menor que 2.1

Versões abaixo da 2.1 pode-se criar um filtro no ficheiro `functions.php`, mas a função é um pouco diferente:

```php
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');

function redirect_to_checkout() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
    return $checkout_url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Set a custom add to cart URL to redirect to
 * @return string
 */
function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() { 
return 'http://www.yourdomain.com/your-page/'; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sabe como eu posso fazer dois botões, um comprar que leve ao checkout, e outro que apenas adicione o produto no carrinho, isso tudo no single product.